# Javascript list filter - Contains any of the words instead of contains

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filter

I have a a script that currently allows me to filter a list based upon an input box. My problem is it filters based the list containing the phrase that I type in rather than containing any of the words that I type in.

Can anyone help me get me tweak this so that it filters based on contains any of the words I type in? For example, if I type in "Primary home", it should filter any list items with the words, Primary or Home.

Currently it searches for "Primary Home" which in this example would show no matches being found.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="myInput" />
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a>MY HOUSE</a></li>
    <li><a>PRIMARY CARE HOME</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: clearly I got this far on my own. I just needed some help changing it from contains to contains any of the words I've typed. I didn't think I was far from where I needed to be. Thank you for the help tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be very much simplified. Start by using `split` to get an array of all the words typed into the input. Then look for any items which contains `some` of the search terms:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const searchTerms = document.querySelector("#myInput").value.toUpperCase().split(" ");
  
  const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li a");
  [...listItems].forEach(a => {
      const txtValue = (a.textContent || a.innerText).toUpperCase();
      a.parentElement.style.display = searchTerms.some(v => txtValue.indexOf(v) > -1) 
            ? "" 
            : "none";
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="myInput" />
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a>MY HOUSE</a></li>
    <li><a>PRIMARY CARE HOME</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to convert the input into arrays with space splits. You can try the below code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase().split(" ");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (filter.includes(txtValue.toUpperCase())) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.onclick = () => myFunction();
```

```html
<div>
<input id="myInput" />
<button>Search</button>
<ul id="myUL">
<li><a>Blue</a></li>
<li><a>Moon</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close, but as a better example if my list had entries like "Primary Care Center A", "Primary Care Center B", "Primary Care Center C"... Ideally if I could type in "primary center" all of the entries here would be shown

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really understood your goal but it seems you are really close to the solution

```
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

    //Here we will split the input value, removing the empty elements if more than one consecutive space
    var allWords = filter.split(' ').filter( e => e !== '');

    var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    var li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        var a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        var txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;


        //is txtValue present in the array?
        if ( allWords.toUpperCase().indexOf(txtValue) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying this code. allWords.toUpperCase is not a function. :-(

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways is using Regex. PLease check the code below.

```js
const li = [
  "How are you",
  "As you know",
  "No i don't",
  "know how",
  "Walls matter",
  "Paint my bed"
];
function check(filter) {
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    const a = li[i];
    const txtValue = a.toUpperCase();
    filter = filter.toUpperCase();
    if (new RegExp(filter.split(" ").join("|")).test(txtValue)) {
      //if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
      console.log(a);
    }
  }
}
check("how do i paint paint my walls");
```